# Injecting a side panel using chrome extension not working

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am developing a chrome extension that performs below function -

1. Get Url path from a webpage. (This webpage path is fixed)
2. Open this Url in a new tab. The Url can be both http:// or https://
3. Inject an iframe in it having a simple html table

I am unable to inject an html table in the new chrome tab opened by the extension. What can I correct so that Step #3 can be performed ?
Please see my code below  -

background.js

```
    var tabId = "";
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse) {    
    //Show the popup
    if (request.message == "Enable_Popup") {
       chrome.pageAction.show(sender.tab.id);
    }

//Get Landing page Url from the fixed webapge   
if (request.message == "Open_LP") {
    chrome.tabs.getSelected(null, function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, { command: "get_url" },function(response){      
    var htmlCode = '<!DOCTYPE html><html style="height:100%"><head><link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css"><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS --><meta charset="utf-8"><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script><title>Konan</title></head><body class="myClass" id="fenxiui" style="height:100%"><div class="col-sm-12"><h1 id="head1" style="align:center">Konan</h1></div><br><br><br><br><iframe id="lp" class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8" src='+response+' style="height:100%"></iframe><iframe id="konanVal" class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4" src="'+val+'" style="height:100%"></iframe>';
    var url = 'data:text/html,' + encodeURIComponent(htmlCode);         
    chrome.tabs.create({"url": response}, function(tab1){               
         chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab1.id, { command: "insert_ifrm" },function(){})
        })})})}})
```

content Script (table.js)

```
    chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(function (msg, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (msg.command && (msg.command == "insert_ifrm")) {
    var valHTML = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><link rel="stylesheet" type ="text/css" href="style.css"><!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS --><meta charset="utf-8"><title>Konan</title></head><body><table><tr><th></th><td>Extraction 1</td></tr><tr><th>Value 1</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 2</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 3</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 4</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 5</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr></table><br><br><table><tr><th></th><td>Extraction 2</td></tr><tr><th>Value 1</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 2</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 3</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 4</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 5</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr></table><br><br><table><tr><th></th><td>Extraction 3</td></tr><tr><th>Value 1</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 2</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 3</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 4</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr><tr><th>Value 5</th><td></td><td><textarea></textarea></td></tr></table></body></html>';
    var ifrm = document.createElement("iframe");
    ifrm.setAttribute("srcdoc", "valHTML");
    ifrm.style.width = "600px";
    ifrm.style.height = "480px";
    ifrm.style.align = "right";
    document.body.appendChild(ifrm);
}
});
```

Comment: Yes, I have my question - What can I correct so that Step #3 can be performed ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct. Did you add `table.js` to `manifest.json` and make sure that it runs on every page? It should looks something like this:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
        "matches": [ "<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["table.js]
       }
]
```